# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON - Socket.IO Client

Tags: typescript, next.js, socket.io, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I use Socket IO with RTK Query and Redux-Toolkit, I have a problem when add Socket like a arg to endpoints RTK-QUERY. How can I fix it?
[image]

[image]
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Query arguments are meant to be really just "data describing the query" - you should usually not pass something like a websocket connection down there. The general recommendation would be to create that outside of a component and just `import` it into your query instead of using it as an argument.